# Obtain both headers and content from single GET request with the Python requests library

Tags: python, parsing, get, python-requests

I am trying to, with a single get request, obtain both headers and content.
At the moment, I am able to obtain them individually:

```
Headers=requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com', verify=False).headers
```

and

```
ParseLM=requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com', verify=False).content
```

However, this makes two separate GET requests while I am trying to parse both headers and content from the same request, although separately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `requests.get()` once, saving the entire result:

```
response = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com', verify=False)
```

Then you can access individual pieces of the result:

```
headers = response.headers
content = response.content
```